# Can't find a way to click on element in Chrome webdriver - Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to click an element with Chrome webdriver but i just can't figure out a way to click it.

The page is showing after i've logged in, so i can't post the website URL

The HTML code of the element is:

```
<gf-dashboard-card class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" href="/chat">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-icon"> 
            <i class="card-icon material-icons ng-
            binding">question_answer</i> 
        </div> 
        <span style="text-
        overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden" 
        class="md-subhead ng-binding">Conversations</span> 
    </div> 
</gf-dashboard-card>
```

I've tried any way that i can't think of to click on the element but i'm always keep getting error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

The xpath of the element is

```
//*[@id="dashboard-cards"]/gf-dashboard-card[1]
```

which gives me nothing.

One interesting thing is that in Firefox webdriver i can click it with

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ng-isolate-scope").click()
```

but it is not working with Chrome. 
I can click the element through the console with

```
$('.md-subhead').click();
```

But haven't figured out how to run this via Selenium.
Any idea how i can run it?

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.md-subhead")`

Comment: add a long sleep before click when debug your code to see the issue is caused by page  not complete loading.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `implicitly_wait` instead of `time.sleep` to wait for the element to become clickable. When the element is found before the 10 second timeout, it will continue instead of waiting the remaining time.

From the documentation:

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount
>   of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately
>   available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is
>   set for the life of the WebDriver object.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dashboard-cards']/gf-dashboard-card[1]").click()
```

Comment: Thanks! it makes more sense to use that rather than time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with loading and waiting time.
Adding:

```
time.sleep(10)
```

And then:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='dashboard-cards']/gf-dashboard-
card[1]").click()
```

It worked well

Comment: Selenium has functions for polling for things like this. See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html .

Comment: but sleep() is not a better solution